# Determine NaN(not a number value)

Tags: c++, nan

I perform some Calculations with floats, and sometimes I divide a number by zero or even zero by zero. As a result, some values of my output array contain -1.#IND0000 values. After that I need to determine whether the value is "normal" or "NaN". How can I do it with if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`isnan()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isnan/).  That's the one you're looking for.

```
#include <math.h>

void YourCode() {

    float x = /* some value from your array here */;
    if (isnan(x)) { 
        // ... do stuff ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks!For my program turned out isfinite() is more useful, but I was not really specific with my question

Comment: C++ is: #include <cmath> and std::isnan(x)